# How to put weekly selection 'datepicker' inside 'swiper'

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, swiper.js

default week selecter datepicker

[image]

Current datepicker screen inside swiper
(week selection events also do not apply.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDk6d.png)

This is an air datepicker that can be selected weekly.
I want to put this datepicker inside the swiper.
I think should add the datepicker event as a swiper option.
The datepicker is not working properly right now. (If I apply the date on slide 1, the date will change on all slides.)

I tried putting the datepicker event into the swiper slideChange and init options, but it keeps failing.

```js
$('.date_week').datepicker({
  language: 'ko',
  autoClose: true,
  navTitles: {
    days: '<span>yyyy</span>년</span>&nbsp;<span>mm</span>월',
    months: '<span>yyyy</span>년',
    years: '<span>yyyy1</span>&nbsp;-</span>&nbsp;<span>yyyy2</span>'
  }
})
const learnWeek = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  allowTouchMove: false,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
var cellCount = 0,
  weekList = [];
var row = createRowSelector();
var rowDetect = false;

var config = {

  week: {
    onShow: function(inst, animated) {
      if (animated) rowDetect = true;
    },
    onHide: function(inst, animated) {
      if (!animated) rowDetect = false;
    },
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
      var $exportWeek = $(".export_week");
      var dateRangeText = getWeekByDateStr(formattedDate).join(" ~ ");
      var combinedText = dateRangeText;
      $exportWeek.html(combinedText);
    }
  },

};


var $picker = $('.date_week');
$picker.datepicker(config.week);
$picker.data('datepicker').selectDate(new Date());


weekSelector();

function weekSelector() {
  $(".datepicker").mouseover(function(e) {
    if (!rowDetect) return;
    if (typeof e.target.className != "string") return;
    if (e.target.className.indexOf("datepicker--cell-day") == -1) return;

    var m = getSundayByDateStr(getDateStrByCell($(e.target)));
    var currentRow = getCellByDateStr(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    currentRow.appendChild(row);
  });
}


function createRowSelector() {
  var r = document.createElement("div");
  r.setAttribute("class", "row");
  return r;
}

function getSundayByDateStr(dateStr) {
  var sunday;
  var year = dateStr.split("-")[0];
  var month = dateStr.split("-")[1];
  var date = dateStr.split("-")[2];
  var day = new Date(year, month - 1, date).getDay();
  var currentDate = moment([year, month, date].join("-"));

  if (day >= 0) {
    sunday = currentDate.clone().subtract(day, 'days');
  }

  return sunday;
}

function getDateStrByCell(cell) {
  var year = parseInt(cell.attr("data-year"));
  var month = parseInt(cell.attr("data-month"));
  var date = parseInt(cell.attr("data-date"));

  console.log(year);
  console.log(month);
  console.log(date);
  return [year, month + 1, date].join("-");
}


function getCellByDateStr(dateStr) {
  var cell;
  var yyyy = parseInt(dateStr.split("-")[0]);
  var mm = parseInt(dateStr.split("-")[1]);
  var dd = parseInt(dateStr.split("-")[2]);

  $.each($(".datepicker--cell-day"), function(i, k) {
    if (k.dataset.year == yyyy && k.dataset.month == mm - 1 && k.dataset.date == dd) {
      cell = k;
      return true;
    }
  });

  return cell;
}

function getWeekByDateStr(dateStr) {
  var week = [];
  var m = getSundayByDateStr(dateStr);

  var sunday = m.format("YYYY.MM.DD");
  var Saturday = m.clone().add(6, "days").format("YYYY.MM.DD");

  week.push(sunday);
  week.push(Saturday);

  weekList = week;
  return week;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { height:50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.1.0/js/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-BKH4s8XuxwAKFAc9tjouyxHsBiZEt/lIsYiJhFgNrFwqu/KluwHSXN2EW5r+DsQ7beF3ZEBJbfpIlqFh49Kz2w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.2.0/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.1.0/css/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mEt69CXdH41K9qBj/MZ54fAyDVV+9Lq/3ElOWl63qHrDUUV4dfYO+8Wou9/fryyc0eplS63V3ICYbDPQ+e0vBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.2.0/swiper-bundle.css" />

<div class="swiper-container">
  <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
    <li class="swiper-slide">
      <input type="text" class="date_week" readonly>
      <span class="export_week"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="swiper-slide">
      <input type="text" class="date_week" readonly>
      <span class="export_week"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="swiper-slide">
      <input type="text" class="date_week" readonly>
      <span class="export_week"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. I found [this airpicker](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/air-datepicker/2.1.0) but that does not like Korean

Comment: next time please create a [mcve] - there are so many libraries needed here and still we get console errors